# Greenpacket OH-735 onboard header

Tags: debugging, serial-communication, jtag

I got myself a Greenpacket OH-735 LTE outdoor unit. On the outside it has a SIM slot and an ethernet interface. Access to the web interface is pretty restricted, not much to set and it is branded with ISP logo (yes, it is used second-hand unit). I tried to contact manufacturer few times but got no response. So I opened it. Found a 8 pin header marked as [NC NC TXD RXD 3V3 1V8 GND GND]. I suppose it is some sort of JTAG or serial interface.

The question is: can anyone help me connect to the interface so I could try to set communication through it (like serial console or something).